Kaczmarz method and terminology
In Kaczmarz method you are itteratively solving simple vector equations $r_i x=b_i$ for matrix $A$, with rows $r_i$ and x shall be multiple of $r_i$. It has solution
$$x = r_i \frac{b_i}{<r_i, r_i>}.$$
Inconvenient is that you have to compute $diag(A A^\top)$ in order to get scalar product of rows of matrix $A$.
My terminological question is whether there is some specific name for $diag(A A^\top)$ vector? If there is no other name, I would call it Kaczmarz product.
And my practical question is whether there would be a way to avoid computing these scalar products by some trick. Since I usually have A and A^T just as operators and it is tricky or expensive to construct $diag(AA^\top)$.

There is no special name for the vector $\text{diag}(AA^T)$. This notation will be understood by everybody who use the diag function in Matlab or is a member of the community on numerical linear algebra. You are free to name it after Kaczmarz, but is there really any reason to introduce a separate term this vector of inner products?
In general, we can expect to have the ability to compute matrix vector products of the form $$y = Ax$$ or $$z = A^Tx$$ at a reasonable cost. It follows that the values $r_i^T r_i$ are readily available because $$r_i = e_i^T A = (A^T e_i)^T$$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th column vector of the appropriate identity matrix.
It is true that the cost of computing $r_i^T r_i$ is not necessarily trivial, but note it can be amortized over multiple iterations of Kaczmarz's method. Moreover, a good reason to use Kaczmarz's is to facilitate the parallel solution of the linear system $$Ax=b.$$ In this context, the number of floating point operations can be much less significant than the number and length of the messages exchanged between the processors involved in the linear solve. This hinges on the fact that arithmetic is typically much faster than communication. This is the celebrated memory wall of scientific computing.
You may wish to read the paper:
R. Bramley and A. Sameh: Domain decomposition for parallel row
projection algorithms
https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-9274(91)90071-7
which concerns generalizations of Kaczmarz's method.
